# Why does the Soyuz cover its main engine?

Tags: soyuz-spacecraft

As seen in Gravity, and also in this youtube video:

, the Soyuz main engine is covered by a metal plate that it mechanically moved out of the way before firing. What is the function of this covering?

[image]

Comment: Maybe it's to protect the nozzles from space debris.

Comment: Could also be to protect the space station's environment from leaking oxidizer.

Comment: would be a micrometeorite cover.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It's to protect the engine from the low temperature.
The cover is removed before the deorbit burn:

[image]

(Source: [Kosmonavtika](http://www.kosmonavtika.com/vaisseaux/soyouz/tech/kdu/kdu.html#2))

$\rightarrow$ During mission [Soyuz-32](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soyuz_32) in 1979, the cosmonauts forgot to open the cover before firing the SKD docked to [Salyut-6](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salyut_6) space station. This was a test burn. The cover was destroyed, and the engines left unprotected. As a protective measure, the station was reoriented so that the Soyuz temperature variations were limited.